# HealthKit requestAuthorization(toShare:, read, completion: ) : is there are way to know whether it was promped at least once?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am currently working with HealthKit and I am wondering: is it possible to know whether the requestAuthorization has been previously asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation, it appears not. You can ask for authorization status for a particular `HKObjectType`, but this will only tell you if can *save* data of that type. You can't tell whether *read* access has been granted. According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614154-authorizationstatus):

> To help prevent possible leaks of sensitive health information, your app cannot determine whether or not a user has granted permission to read data.

You can call `requestAuthorization` [repeatedly](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614152-requestauthorization), and the user will only be prompted if they have not previously granted access to the `HKObjectType`'s requested:

> If the user has already chosen to grant or prohibit access to all of the types specified, the completion is called without prompting the user.